# How to lock the worksheet's name in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

This is how i make changes in the sheet,i want to lock the sheet names for user as it is being used as reference and cannot be changed midway

`xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)
xlWorkSheet.Cells(6, 1).Value = cmb_ref.SelectedValue.ToString                          xlWorkSheet.Name = cmb_ref.SelectedValue.ToString + "-1"
xlWorksheet.Activate()`

The user has to enter values and use macros in them,so i cant lock the contents.
Is this possible?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an event handler for a sheet/object being renamed.